# Is there any way to compel compiler not to remove an arbitrary variable from cache memory?

Tags: c, caching, gcc, gnu

My anxiety is performance of program which has been written in `C` language. It's clear that memory access time is a large amount of total time consumed by processor. All i want is to move some part of data to cache memory to improve performance.

After some searches i found an approach with Gnu C Compiler(gcc) that is this function:

`_builtin_prefetch()`.

This function pulls arbitrary variable from memory before it's actual call stage, but how to use this function effectively?

Actually i do not find [GNU manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) helpful itself. Any effective example of using this function or even other compilers solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have to handle your cache memory manually? What kind of application are we talking about? I think this is more a design issue. Clever code can hardly compensate for bad design.

Comment: Usually problems like this can be fixed elsewhere in the code. If you resort to meddling with cache you are probably taking the wrong approach.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves In case of high performance computing we are facing many troubles like that not because of design issues but because of problem nature and demand for speed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `register` modifier when you create the variable but, it is not guaranteed that the variable will be stored in cache. All I know is that there is no way to be sure if the variable gonna be in cache or not, you cannot  just hope to the compiler to do that. If you want, you must use Assembly of your target to get that.

Example:

```
register int variable;
```

The `register` modifier can be used only with integers variables.

Comment: could you please tell me more about registry instructions you mentioned? my data is more than a variable.

Comment: `register`has nothing to do with cache. It just instructs the compiler to put a variable into one of the processor's registers, if possible.